# GitLab runners on k3s error ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I can see that my POD is created but the build log says this.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.3.0 (8ec04662)
  on gitlab-runner-679d6544d7-2cnnp -cU7jBwtk, system ID: r_FmvSLQ5mgJMU

Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner
Using Kubernetes executor with image ubuntu:22.04 ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...

Preparing environment
00:06
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner--cu7jbwtk-project-1-concurrent-0-qv72z26e to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner--cu7jbwtk-project-1-concurrent-0-qv72z26e to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    PodFailed: ""
    PodFailed: ""
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pod status is failed. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

any idea what might be wrong with my set up?

configuring a GitLab Runner on K3S